# Attempting to install libGDX - error updating Eclipse to Kepler

Tags: eclipse, libgdx, eclipse-kepler

My goal is to install **libGDX** in Eclipse. To do that, I want to make sure Eclipse is up to date.

I checked my Eclipse version by going to Help - About ADT - Eclipse logo, which says my Eclipse Platform is 4.2.1.

I ensured that the following URLs were in my Window - Preferences - Available software sites*:

- http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3
- http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse
- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler

(note that there are other URLs in my available software sites as well)

Then I went to Help - Check for updates

The error message was: No updates were found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "install" libgdx. You add the libgdx jars and configure your projects to use them.

Right now you can use the [SetupUi](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/dist/gdx-setup-ui.jar) tool to do all that automatically. Also, you don't need to update eclipse for that.

Comment: Cool thanks. The setup tool looks ace. Though I am still having a problem updating my version of Eclipse, as stated above. Doesn't necessarily relate to libGDX anymore, but I would still like to update.

Comment: Thats weird, "Check for Updates" has always worked for me. Why dont you export your preferences (formatters etc) and simply download the new version?

Comment: I know this sounds weird, but I've actually done a full reinstall, using the official SDK ADT Bundle (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) just yesterday. Still, when I check my Eclipse version, it still clearly states: Eclipse Platform 4.2.1. I agree that the official bundle would normally be the latest version, would it not?

Comment: Well, it comes from the android developers site, so probably not. I have never used the bundle :p

Comment: Right, right. So I just went to the actual Eclipse site and have downloaded Kepler. It's pretty... Now just to add the plug ins separately.

Comment: **Fix:** Instead of downloading the ADT SDK bundle, I did a fresh download of Eclipse only, then added the SDK tools/ADT plugin/platform tools/platform/system image separately. From the official Eclipse site, I could download Eclipse 4.3.

Then I downloaded Google plugin 4.3. It just seemed to work fine. So there seemed to be a problem with the Eclipse 4.2 and Google plugin 4.2 combo